# How do you bundle getters in Java?

Tags: java, methods, getter

```
public String getPet() {
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public String getType(){
        return type;
    }
    public String getDescription() {
    }
    return description;
 }
```

I would like to bundle three getters into one, so that getPet()
gets getName(), getType(), and getDescription(). I typed this out, but there is something wrong with my syntax that I cannot figure out.

Comment: What do you expect the return type to be of this?  You can't have methods inside of methods.  If it just returns a `Pet`, then all you need is `return yourPet`.

Comment: `return description;` should be inside of `getDescription`

Comment: I have never heard of "bundling" getters. Why don't you just return or access the `Pet` object assuming `Pet` is a class...

Answer (score 2):

You cannot directly have nested methods in Java. You can call as many methods as you want inside of a method though.

So you could have something like this

```
public Pet getPet() {
    getName();
    getType();
    getDescription();
    // create a pet from these method calls and return it i suppose?
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}
public String getType(){
    return type;
}
public String getDescription() {
    return description;
}
```

Like others have said though, there is no real reason that I could see to do this.

Answer (score 1):

What you want is redundant, but here it comes another funny but valid option:

```
public Pet {
...
  public Pet getPet(){
    return this;
  }
}
```

Then you can access all your methods from getPet(), but, as I said this is redundand:

```
Pet p = new Pet();
Pet q = p.getPet();
```

So you can access, from getPet() all of the other methods:

```
p.getPet().getName();
p.getPet().getType();
p.getPet().getDescription();
```

But that's redundant, since you can access these directly:

```
p.getName();
p.getType();
p.getDescription();
```

It is pretty probable, there's some misunderstanding on the Object Oriented fundamentals you're trying to implement. May I suggest, take a read to: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/concepts/index.html

Comment: You're right. I've been programming in JavaScript for two years, but in Java for only two months, starting with Spring Boot. I'll take a look at the docs you recommended, I am very new to OOP in Java.